# Can't import class from custom python module

Tags: python

There is a blank `NatMailer/__init__.py`.

Here's:
`NatMailer/NatMailer.py`

```
# python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
class NatMailer:
    def __init__(self, smtp_server="localhost", port=1025, sender_email="example@example.com", debug=0):
        import logging

        logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.info("Initiating NatMailer")

        import smtplib, ssl
        import json
        import csv
        import sqlite3

        sql = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
        self.debug = debug
        if (debug):
            self.smtp_server = "localhost"
            self.port = 1025
            self.sender_email = "example@example.com"
        else:
            self.smtp_server = smtp_server
            self.port = port
            self.sender_email = sender_email
    def send_email(self, receiver_email, message_contents):
        # Create a secure SSL context
        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        logging.info("Sending new email")

        # Try to log in to server and send email
        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_server,self.port)
            server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
            if (not self.debug):
                logging.info("Logging into " + self.sender_email)
                server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
                server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
                server.login(self.sender_email, self.password)
            logging.info("Sending email to " + receiver_email)
            server.sendmail(self.sender_email, receiver_email, message_contents)
        except Exception as e:
            # Print any error messages to stdout
            logging.debug(e)
        finally:
            server.quit()
```

Then there is a `debug_driver.py` outside of `NatMailer/`.

```
import NatMailer
debug = 1
nm = NatMailer.NatMailer(debug=debug)
message = """\
            Subject: Hi there

            This message is sent from Python."""
nm.send_email('someone@gmail.com', message)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pat/PycharmProjects/NatMailer/debug_driver.py", line 3, in <module>
    nm = NatMailer.NatMailer(debug=debug)
AttributeError: module 'NatMailer' has no attribute 'NatMailer'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to import a custom class into my debug_driver.py script.

Comment: To help you keep track of which thing is which, follow the Python naming guidelines and use lowercase names for modules. Then, at least, you would have a module `natmailer.natmailer` that contains a class `NatMailer`. Also, consider whether you really need a module with the same name as its containing package; you can put the class `NatMailer` directly in `natmailer/__init__.py` to do away with the intermediate module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three levels involved here: directory (package), filename (module), and class. `NatMailer` refers to the package, `NatMailer.NatMailer` refers to the module, and `NatMailer.NatMailer.NatMailer` refers to the class.

So you would need something like

```
# import module from package
import NatMailer.NatMailer  

debug = 1
nm = NatMailer.NatMailer.NatMailer(debug=debug)
```

---

Brief explanation of the error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'NatMailer' has no attribute 'NatMailer'
```

You import just the package (or module, as stated here):

```
import NatMailer
```

That basically only loads the `__init__.py` file, which is empty. Hence, when you try to access anything of that module, Python will complain, because there is nothing there:

```
NatMailer.NatMailer
```

The attribute doesn't exist: it's not the (sub)module, because that isn't imported in `__init__.py`, nor is it the class, since that wasn't imported in `__init__.py` either. It's basically a near-empty import, and you'd have to explicitly import `NatMailer.NatMailer`. But see above and below.

---

Alternatives:

1/

```
# import module from package
from NatMailer import NatMailer  

debug = 1
nm = NatMailer.NatMailer(debug=debug)
```

2/

```
# import class from the module directly
from NatMailer.NatMailer import NatMailer  

debug = 1
nm = NatMailer(debug=debug)
```

3/ Slight more involved perhaps, but quite often used:

Put this in your package `__init__.py`:

```
from .NatMailer import NatMailer
```

and then use

```
# import the class from package
# note: now you can't distinguish the class from the module.
# see the remark at the bottom about naming conventions
from NatMailer import NatMailer  

debug = 1
nm = NatMailer(debug=debug)
```

Since the `NatMailer` class can now be found at package level, not just at module level.

---

Note: packages and modules are usually not CamelCased. That would make things slightly more insightful: `natmailer.natmailer.NatMailer` would be your class.

Comment: Alternatively, in the `__init__.py` file do `from NatMailer import NataMailer`, then the original import would work.

Comment: ah ha, I'll accept this answer soon. Very insightful. I'll fix the CamelCase as well.